Does importing schema bring in with it the password and other data like table space?
In oracle database does importing a schema bring in with it the password and other data like table space.
Will the schema itself be created if there is no schema in the Database??
What about the table spaces.

What do you mean by "bring in with it the password" ?

During the schema import if at all the schema user is also created with the import If I have a schema A with password ABC on the source when I import it on the target I want the same password to coming in with the import. Is that feasilble.
